# image of Kummer isomorphism

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, galois-representations, galois-cohomology, kummer-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of the field of $p$-adic numbers which contains the $p$-roots of unity.

There is an isomorphism $K^{\times} / (K^{\times})^p \to \mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Gal} (\bar{K} / K), \mathbb{F}_p)$ which sends $x$ to the map $\sigma \mapsto \dfrac{\sigma(x^{1/p})}{x^{1/p}}$.

Call this isomorphism $\delta$.

Is there a way to decide whether $\delta(x)$ is a ramified or unramified character (depending maybe on the fact that $x$ is an integer in $K$ or not) ?

Answer (score 2):

Let me call $\alpha$ the Kummer map $K^{\times} / (K^{\times})^p \to \mathrm{Hom}(G_K, \mu_p)$. (It's more canonical to use $\mu_p$ than $\mathbb F_p$, unless you have chosen a specific $p$th root of $1$ in $K$). Suppose that $\alpha(x)$ is unramified. This means that

$$\frac{\sigma(x^{1/p})}{x^{1/p}} = 1$$

for every $\sigma$ in the inertia group $I \subset G_K$. In other words, ${\sigma(x^{1/p})} = {x^{1/p}}$, or, what is the same, $I$ acts trivially on $K(x^{1/p})$. This means precisely that the extension $K(x^{1/p})/K$ is unramified. Since $v(x^{1/p}) = v(x)/p$, the extension will be unramified precisely when $v(x) \in p \cdot v(K^\times)$, in other words when the valuation of $x$ is divisible by $p$ in the valuation group of $K$. (Note that this is not the same as saying that $x$ is a $p$th power in $K$.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible though to obtain a sufficient condition ? The unramified characters are just a line in the $\mathbb{F}_p$ vector space $\mathrm{Hom}(G_K, \mu_p)$ : is it possible to characterize this line in $K^{\times} / (K^{\times})^p$ ?

Comment: Isn't "the valuation of $x$ is divisible by $p$ in the valuation group of $K$" a complicated way of saying that $x$ is in the image of $O_K^\times$ in $K^\times / K^{\times p}$?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you've written, this claim is incorrect, since e.g. taking $p =2$, the element $-1 \in \mathbb Q_2^{\times}$ has valuation zero, while $\mathbb Q_2(i)/\mathbb Q_2$ is ramified.